# Deformation of Heated Transmission Cable in a Conduit

Tags: wire, power-engineering

Say I have 2000' feet of single phase XLPE cable with a 4" outer diameter in a 6" conduit, for simplicity, assume the conduit's inner diameter is 6".  Also assume the cable is pinned at both ends and isn't free to expand except into the residual space of the conduit.  Further, assume the conduit is rigid but the cable isn't.  I can figure the expansion and the strain, that's no big deal, my problem is understanding the math of cable deformation inside the conduit.  Since the cable will be pinned, it will deform.  I assume that the deformations will take some sigmoidal shape inside the conduit (this remains to be proven), which we can assume will not deform.  I'd like to know the math of solving a problem like this because I've been tasked with writing a paper in which this situation exists. Also, I apologize if this is in the wrong forum as I'm not sure exactly what forum it should be in from the list I looked at.  Further, my search: "cable thermal expansion in a conduit" "Your search returned no matches."
Edit: the current carrying cross sectional area is about 2.5 square inches, or 1600mm^2, which gives a slenderness ratio just over 9000.
Edit2: Some re-wording of the question to eliminate potentially confusing terms.

Comment: Is this purely academic, or does this installation actually exist / is it planned to exist?

I've never heard of cable buckling due to thermal expansion as a practical design consideration.

Comment: Also, "bending radius" usually has the specific meaning "the minimum bending radius of the cable to avoid permanent damage" - probably not what you meant by "bending radius". You should try to use a different term, to avoid confusion.

Comment: When bending power conduit for buildings, the minimum  recommended radius is 7 times the conduit diameter. The cable manufacture will specify their minimum.

Comment: Li, it's not purely academic, results will bear on measures taken to reduce the ill effects of expansion in present/future designs. Is curve radius more to your liking?  Splices fail from expansion and they aren't cheap to repair. These are transmission cables, Option, not distribution, but thanks.

Comment: Re-tag was me, I've corrected the tags.

Comment: Re-tagging isn't a problem, thank you, Li. I'm beginning to think this question belongs in a physics or applied math forum.  Maybe I should look around?

Comment: I'm not sure where to find a community of HV engineers with practical installation experience, who also answer questions on the internet. If you find one let me know, because I will go there as well!

Comment: Ha-ha, rare birds indeed.  If I find them, I'll be sure to let you know ;)

Comment: FYI, `cable thermal expansion -minecraft` gives some good search results, including http://cr4.globalspec.com/thread/26938/Calculating-Thermal-Expansion-for-Power-Cables which points to a book by Siemens. The issue of overstressing cable joints / splices is explicitly mentioned. (The `-minecraft` is required to exclude results from the Minecraft mod "Thermal Expansion" - which I quite like, incidentally.)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a direct answer to the question of "calculate the deformation of cable due to thermal expansion", but rather an attempt at a practical solution.

Firstly, I have sketched my understanding of the problem below.

[image]

I have seen piping designs where long, straight sections of pipe have U-shaped sections inserted to account for thermal expansion of the pipework. The expansion is taken up by flexing of the U-parts.

[image]

Depending on the bending radius of your cable it may be possible to solve your problem in a similar way. Insert an intentional bend in the cable every few hundred meters. Thermal expansion would be taken up by expansion/contraction of the bend.

[image]

A practical design is likely to require cable pits at 100-200m intervals. These cable pits are required to pull the cable through in stages, so the pull tension is kept low enough. (Pulling 2,000 ft. = 600 metres of cable at once would likely require an excessive pulling tension, which would damage the cable by elongation.)

Your problem may be practically solved by putting bends in these pits, allowing for thermal expansion in specific places where you have designed to allow it.

A full loop of cable would probably require an excessively large pit. A few shallower bends would likely be suffficient - see below.

[image]

Regularly spaced "expansion pits" would be analogous to putting expansion joints in concrete slabs, to allow expansion of the concrete.

---

Edit:

- Assume copper cable.
- Assume the cable's length is determined by thermal expansion of the
  copper conductor. (Disregard the thermal expansion of the XLPE
  plastic insulation.)
- Assume the cable temperature varies from 25 C (ambient) to 90 C
  (upper limit for XLPE) so that \$ \Delta T = 65^{\circ} C \$.
- The linear thermal co-efficient of expansion of copper is \$ 16.6 \times 10^{-6} 
     m_{expansion} / ( m_{original length} . ^{\circ} C ) \$ .

Then the thermal expansion of a 600m length of cable will be approximately \$ 1.66 \times 10^{-6} \times 600 m \times 65^{\circ} C \approx 70cm \$, which seems modest enough. It could be absorbed by allowing for 20cm expansion in each of four cable pits along the route.

Comment: Yes, thermal expansion will be controlled by copper.  My suggestion was to add a pull through vault, but perhaps I like your term expansion pits better, but the owner insists that a curving alignment will accommodate the growth.  Your operating temperatures are good except the cable is allowed 5 second 250C operation maybe three times in its service life. I'm aware of expansion loops. They can't be used in duct banks. I appreciate the trouble you've gone through. It irks me that I can't math out the problem, which you illustrated pretty well.

Comment: I can imagine the trouble with fitting full loops of cable into a pit with multiple 1,600mm² cables going through it! Perhaps the "expansion pit" I've pictured, with a half-bend, would be easier to construct.

Comment: I agree, an "expansion pit' would be the better solution, however, the owner insists a serpentine route would solve the problem and I don't agree, I believe a straight alignment is equal to a curved alignment, but I need the math of how the cable will deform to convince the owner. That's why the question.

Comment: If the duct is curved then, even without the cable taking up complicated serpentine patterns within it, you can calculate the shortest and the longest path through the duct that the cable could occupy (basically the inside and the outside of each bend).  The difference between those two numbers should give you some idea if the owner's right or not.

Comment: @WillDean's comment is instructive. Consider: A string wrapped around the Earth is ~ 80,000,000 m long. A string encircling the earth at an altitude of 1 inch is only 6.28 inches longer. Which is to say - a gently curving 150mm/6" conduit is probably NOT going to allow 70 cm of thermal expansion.

Comment: I started out assuming the curved route would be better and found the expandable space to be the same as the straight route. The extra length of cable required to traverse the length and the fact that expansion is delta unit/unit makes it a wash. Good thinking, though, and thanks.